# kedro: Used azure key and scope, then pull data from snowflake via databricks cluster

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, kedro

I'm currently running into a requirement where we are using a scope/key credential to access/grab data from our Snowflake instance, then load it in our blob storage, while using our Databricks cluster. I was already able to do those things in a Databricks notebook, but when porting it into our Kedro framework, it fails.

Has anyone done this and can you give an example of a format where you add your azure scope/key and use it in a Kedro catalog?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can load external credentials easily with a hook.

See this example:
https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/hooks/common_use_cases.html#use-hooks-to-load-external-credentials